# values are not populating in the jquery datatable for a grails application

Tags: jquery, grails, datatables

I am fetching a list of values from the `controller-action` to load into the `data-table`.I have checked that values are getting fetched succesfully from my controller action, but the values are not getting load ed into the `data-table`.And it shows

> No data available

Here is my Controller.

```html
package com.standout.utilityapplication
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.annotation.Secured

@Secured(['ROLE_ADMIN'])
class ReportController {
 AdminService adminService
    def report() { 
  
  println ("--Inside ReportController");
 }
 def searchAjax(){
  String criteria = params.search_criteria
  println ("criteria "+criteria)
  if(criteria.equalsIgnoreCase("Employee ID")){
  def resultSet = adminService.getReportById(params) 
  println("----------------+++++ "+resultSet)
  [bill_details:resultSet]
  }
  
}
}
```

Here is my GSP.

```html
<html>
<head>
   <title>Report</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/dataTables.jqueryui.min.css"/>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/dataTables.jqueryui.min.js"></script>
<script>
function displayTable(){
 $(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable();
 })
 document.getElementById('reportSearch').style.display = ''
 
}
 </script>
</head>
<body>
<g:formRemote name="billSearchForm" class="form-horizontal" onComplete="displayTable()" url="[controller: 'Report', action:'searchAjax']">
<div id="reportSearch" style="border-bottom: 1px solid;display:none;padding-right:45px;" class="col-sm-9">
<br/>
<br/>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Employee Id</th>
                <th>Bill Date</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
                <th>No. of Persons</th>
                <th>Bank Submission Date</th>
                <th>Bank Submission Status</th>
                <th>Bill Date</th>
                <th>Reimbursed</th>
                <th>Restaurant Name</th>
                <th>Team</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Employee Id</th>
                <th>Bill Date</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
                <th>No. of Persons</th>
                <th>Bank Submission Date</th>
                <th>Bank Submission Status</th>
                <th>Bill Date</th>
                <th>Reimbursed</th>
                <th>Restaurant Name</th>
                <th>Team</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
        <g:each in="${bill_details}" var="it">
            <tr>
                <td>${it.employee_id}</td>
                <td>${it.bill_submitted_dt}</td>
                <td>${it.amount}</td>
                <td>${it.number_of_persons}</td>
                <td>${it.presented_bank_dt}</td>
                <td>${it.presented_bank_fl}</td>
                <td>${it.receipt_dt}</td>
                <td>${it.reimbursed}</td>
                <td>${it.restaurant_name}</td>
                <td>${it.team}</td>
            </tr>
            </g:each>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<br/>
<br/>
</div>
</g:formRemote>
</body>
  </html>
```

Could anyone tell me what to do?

Comment: So in controller when you print, the data is fine, right? And what if you simply print it out `${bill_details.size()}` in gsp? what does it show?

Comment: I think there is problem with your gsp / jquery code.

Answer (score 0):

Please try using below code snippest.

`html-table` content from `gsp` file
 You can add other custom things to the table as per your wish.

```
              <table id="userDataTable" class="table table-bordered table-striped tableWidth dataTable">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Branch Name</th>
                                <th>User Name</th>
                                <th>First Name</th>
                                <th>Last Name</th>
                                <th>Contact Number</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                        </table>
```

`jquery` content for **loading / pouplating** data in the `data-table`

```
var userDetailsDataTable = "";

userDetailsDataTableReload :  function(){

userDetailsDataTable = $('#userDataTable').DataTable();
userDetailsDataTable.destroy();

userDetailsDataTable = $('#userDataTable').DataTable({
    "ajax": '../restaurantManagement/fetchUserDetails'
});

}
```

from here, we are giving call to the controller action  `fetchUserDetails`

`controller-action` content

```
    Map userDetailsMap      =   [:]

    List userDetailsList    =   userManagementService.fetchAllUsersByRestaurantId(restaurantId)

    userDetailsMap << [data : userDetailsList]

    render userDetailsMap as JSON
```

Let me know if it gives you problem.

Answer (score 0):

You make an error in the use of the g:formRemote
I don't know your grails version, but this link gives you details and you should accord importance to following attributes : update, onComplete

http://docs.grails.org/2.4.5/ref/Tags/formRemote.html

In your case I think you should use onComplete event
because in your code you try to display bill_details but you cannot like this, it is evaluated during the ajax call but not automatically replace in your code.

With update attribute you can specify for example the id of a div tag, in which the result of your ajax call will be displayed.

In your case you should use the onComplete event attribute and return bill_details in a JSON format like this :

```
def searchAjax(){
    ...
    def result = [bill_details:resultSet]
    render result as JSON
}
```

Then in your gsp code specify the onComplete attribute like this :

```
<g:formRemote name="billSearchForm" class="form-horizontal" onComplete="displayTable(data)" url="[controller: 'Report', action:'searchAjax']">
```

data will allow you to access the JSON result of your ajax call

then in your displayTable you'll be able to iterate on the JSON data bill_details